# Настройка переключения кнопок c помощью js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет!

Такая проблема: есть виртуальное пианино, 2 кнопки, нажимаешь на первую - отображаются ноты, нажимаешь на вторую - отображаются буквы на клавиатуре, которые надо нажать.

Проблема в том, что когда нажимаешь на кнопку, переключается режим, а когда нажимаешь на нее же опять, то опять меняется, но меняться не должно. А то получается путаница.

Сам код:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
const piano = document.querySelector('.piano');

for (let button of buttons) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        buttons.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('btn-active'));

        this.classList.toggle('btn-active');
        piano.classList.toggle('change-style');
    });
};
```

```css
    .btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: #454c53;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.btn:not(.btn-active):hover {
  background-color: #515961;
}
.btn:active {
  background-color: #00c9b7;
}
.btn-active {
  background-color: #00b4a4;
}
.btn-active:hover {
  background-color: #00c9b7;
}
.piano {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 270px;
  max-width: 560px;
  margin: 0 auto 60px;
}
.piano-key {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 270px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  border: 4px solid #313940;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 12px 12px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.piano-key:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.keys-sharp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 53px;
  right: 53px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.piano-key.sharp {
  width: 54px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: #313940;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 9px 9px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.piano-key.piano-key-active,
.piano-key.sharp.piano-key-active {
  transform: scale(0.96);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #4fb8a6;
}
.piano-key.none {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.piano-key::before,
.piano-key::after {
  content: attr(data-note);
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #a2b3b0;
  bottom: -45px;
  left: 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.piano.change-style .piano-key::before,
.piano.change-style .piano-key::after {
  content: attr(data-letter);
}
.piano-key::after {
  display: none;
  content: attr(data-letter);
}
.piano-key:hover::before,
.piano-key:hover::after {
  color: #cbd5de;
}
.piano-key:active::before,
.piano-key:active::after {
  color: #4fb8a6;
}
.piano-key.sharp::before,
.piano-key.sharp::after {
  bottom: 175px;
  left: 7px;
}
.piano-key.letter::before {
  display: none;
}
.piano-key.letter::after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
    <div class="btn-container">
        <button class="btn btn-notes btn-active">Notes</button>
        <button class="btn btn-letters">Letters</button>
    </div>
    <div class="piano">
        <div class="piano-key" data-key="68" data-letter="D" data-note="c"></div>
        <div class="piano-key" data-key="70" data-letter="F" data-note="d"></div>
        <div class="piano-key" data-key="71" data-letter="G" data-note="e"></div>
        <div class="piano-key" data-key="72" data-letter="H" data-note="f"></div>
        <div class="piano-key" data-key="74" data-letter="J" data-note="g"></div>
        <div class="piano-key" data-key="75" data-letter="K" data-note="a"></div>
        <div class="piano-key" data-key="76" data-letter="L" data-note="b"></div>
        <div class="keys-sharp">
            <div class="piano-key sharp" data-key="82" data-letter="R" data-note="c♯"></div>
            <div class="piano-key sharp" data-key="84" data-letter="T" data-note="d♯"></div>
            <div class="piano-key sharp none"></div>
            <div class="piano-key sharp" data-key="85" data-letter="U" data-note="f♯"></div>
            <div class="piano-key sharp" data-key="73" data-letter="I" data-note="g♯"></div>
            <div class="piano-key sharp" data-key="79" data-letter="O" data-note="a♯"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="fullscreen openfullscreen" onclick="fullscreen();"></button>
</main>
```

Comment: Наверное вам стОит добавить в вопрос html и css

Answer (score 5):

`piano.classList.toggle('change-style');` — Ошибка тут, класс переключается при любом клике, независимо от нажатой кнопки. Чтобы не добавлять хитрые условия, легче изначально прервать функцию, если кликнули на кнопку, у которой и так уже есть нужный класс.

```js
const piano = document.querySelector('.piano');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

for (let button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.classList.contains('btn-active')) return; // <--

    buttons.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('btn-active'));

    this.classList.add('btn-active'); // <-- toggle заменил на add, т.к.
    // здесь не было никакого переключения, он всегда срабатывал как add.

    piano.classList.toggle('change-style');
  });
};
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: #454c53;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.btn:not(.btn-active):hover {
  background-color: #515961;
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: #00c9b7;
}

.btn-active {
  background-color: #00b4a4;
}

.btn-active:hover {
  background-color: #00c9b7;
}

.piano {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 270px;
  max-width: 560px;
  margin: 0 auto 60px;
}

.piano-key {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 270px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  border: 4px solid #313940;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 12px 12px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.piano-key:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.keys-sharp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 53px;
  right: 53px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.piano-key.sharp {
  width: 54px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: #313940;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 9px 9px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.piano-key.piano-key-active,
.piano-key.sharp.piano-key-active {
  transform: scale(0.96);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #4fb8a6;
}

.piano-key.none {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.piano-key::before,
.piano-key::after {
  content: attr(data-note);
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #a2b3b0;
  bottom: -45px;
  left: 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.piano.change-style .piano-key::before,
.piano.change-style .piano-key::after {
  content: attr(data-letter);
}

.piano-key::after {
  display: none;
  content: attr(data-letter);
}

.piano-key:hover::before,
.piano-key:hover::after {
  color: #cbd5de;
}

.piano-key:active::before,
.piano-key:active::after {
  color: #4fb8a6;
}

.piano-key.sharp::before,
.piano-key.sharp::after {
  bottom: 175px;
  left: 7px;
}

.piano-key.letter::before {
  display: none;
}

.piano-key.letter::after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
  <button class="btn btn-notes btn-active">Notes</button>
  <button class="btn btn-letters">Letters</button>
</div>
<div class="piano">
  <div class="piano-key" data-key="68" data-letter="D" data-note="c"></div>
  <div class="piano-key" data-key="70" data-letter="F" data-note="d"></div>
  <div class="piano-key" data-key="71" data-letter="G" data-note="e"></div>
  <div class="piano-key" data-key="72" data-letter="H" data-note="f"></div>
  <div class="piano-key" data-key="74" data-letter="J" data-note="g"></div>
  <div class="piano-key" data-key="75" data-letter="K" data-note="a"></div>
  <div class="piano-key" data-key="76" data-letter="L" data-note="b"></div>
  <div class="keys-sharp">
    <div class="piano-key sharp" data-key="82" data-letter="R" data-note="c♯"></div>
    <div class="piano-key sharp" data-key="84" data-letter="T" data-note="d♯"></div>
    <div class="piano-key sharp none"></div>
    <div class="piano-key sharp" data-key="85" data-letter="U" data-note="f♯"></div>
    <div class="piano-key sharp" data-key="73" data-letter="I" data-note="g♯"></div>
    <div class="piano-key sharp" data-key="79" data-letter="O" data-note="a♯"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="fullscreen openfullscreen" onclick="fullscreen();"></button>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее, добрый человек))